# Validating fileupload and disabling submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have this `RegularExpressionValidator` for my file upload, it only accepts for `.jpg`:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidator" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ForeColor="red" Font-Size="Smaller"
ErrorMessage="Only JPEG images are allowed"
ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg])$)">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

the problem is, when I try to choose another file type instead of `jpg/jpeg` the error message is showing, but when i tried to click the submit button, it submits.

I'm thinking of disabling and enabling the submit button until the inputs are perfectly validated, but i dont know how does the `jquery` work with the `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can prevent the form submission action by checking a boolean from your regular expression and then prevent default on it:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
    if(!(boolean)){
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Edit: Missed that the Regex was coming from ASP, but you could use asp to set an attribute on the form and then check the form attribute using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the `ValidationGroup` in your submit button is bound to another group....

Also, you should note that when posting back it's considered best practise to recheck your validators with the Page.IsValid method (this because it's not guaranteed that your validators triggered in the browser--for instance, javascript was turned off, etc...)

Sample code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check that validators are valid
    if (!Page.IsValid)  
        return;

   //save image
}
```